# Cisco ASA 5505 ipsec - Can't create IKEV2

Tags: cisco, vpn

I'm trying to migrate an ASA 5505 to IKEV2 using *migrate l2l* with CLI and get this error:

*ERROR: ipsec policy insertion failed because the maximum proposal limit of 20 was exceeded*

The ASA OS is 9.2.3 and there is currently a site to site VPN tunnel with IKEV1

I've straightened out the policies - I believe - but while the IKEV1 tunnel works the V2 doesn't. Here is the configuration:

```
ASA Version 9.2(3) 
!
hostname sollo
domain-name domain.com
enable password .XXXXXXXXXXXXX encrypted
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain
passwd XXXXXXXXXXXXX encrypted
names
ip local pool vpool 192.168.20.10-192.168.20.20 mask 255.255.255.0
ip local pool mypool 192.168.11.10-192.168.11.20 mask 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.100.101.254 255.255.255.0 
 ospf cost 10
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 12.34.56.78 255.255.255.248 
 ospf cost 10
!
boot system disk0:/asa923-k8.bin
boot system disk0:/asa847-31-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name domain.com
object network obj-10.100.101.0
 subnet 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj-10.100.100.0
 subnet 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.101.0_24
 subnet 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.100.200.0_24
 subnet 10.100.200.0 255.255.255.0
object-group service allowedports tcp
 port-object eq pptp
access-list tomiddle extended permit ip 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list split standard permit 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0 
no pager
logging enable
logging asdm notifications
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-731-101.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,any) source static obj-10.100.101.0 obj-10.100.101.0 destination static obj-10.100.100.0 obj-10.100.100.0 no-proxy-arp
!
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 64.223.94.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authorization command LOCAL 
http server enable
http 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 inside
http 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set myset esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-3DES-MD5
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-256-MD5
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-256-SHA
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-192-MD5
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-192-SHA
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-128-MD5
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal ESP-AES-128-SHA
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal myset
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
 crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging 20
crypto dynamic-map outside_dyn_map 20 set pfs group5
crypto dynamic-map outside_dyn_map 20 set ikev1 transform-set myset
crypto dynamic-map outside_dyn_map 40 set pfs group5
crypto dynamic-map outside_dyn_map 40 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto map mymap 10 match address tomiddle
crypto map mymap 10 set peer 87.65.43.21 
crypto map mymap 10 set ikev1 transform-set myset
crypto map mymap 10 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES myset
crypto map mymap 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic outside_dyn_map
crypto map mymap interface outside
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 am-disable
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 10.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh 10.100.101.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh timeout 60
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 3
management-access inside

dhcpd address 10.100.101.70-10.100.101.73 inside
    !
threat-detection basic-threat
no threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-idle-timeout none
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 l2tp-ipsec 
username phsrx password LFjGdPBp3.PJH2wz encrypted privilege 15
tunnel-group 87.65.43.21 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 87.65.43.21 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
  inspect icmp 
  inspect icmp error 
 !

service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:18ae193gervtt3tv3565436j3456eth06ed
: end
```

Comment: You really need to edit your question to provide more detail. Start with the configurations.

Comment: Since you figured it out, you should post an answer and accept it, otherwise the question will keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: @Ron Maupin Thank you I did and apologies - I'm new to Stackexchange.

Comment: No problem. We get a lot of old questions popping up from time to time, where the author of the question answered it or discovered the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. After reviewing the configuration and not seeing anything off I entered new keys on both sides of the tunnel and it came up immediately. I had been given some incorrect information.

Answer (score 0):

Each configuration supports a maximum of 20 ISAKMP policies, each with a different set of values. Assign a unique priority to each policy you create. The lower the priority number, the higher the priority. Just simple you cannot have more than 20 ISAKMP policies. You can add additional ISAKMP policies by deleting unsed one.

As per: [LINK](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/conf_gd/ike.html)

Comment: I should have included config information, sorry:

Comment: I've figured it out. After reviewing the configuration and not seeing anything off I entered new keys on both sides of the tunnel and it came up immediately.